# Can I have temporary swap space greater than 2x RAM?

Tags: ram, swap

I have 8G RAM. I know how to create and use a temporary swapfile. I need to have ~30G of memory to run a pandas computation, but **everywhere I check the recommended upper limit of swap file seems to be 2x RAM**.

Can I create and use a **22G** swapfile on my system without causing any trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough space available on your storage device, you can designate a swap partition as large as you like.  The real question is whether you'll gain anything from making it larger.

Unfortunately, simply having 22 GB of swap on top of your 8 GB physical RAM isn't at all the same as having 30 GB for your running program.  The thrashing of memory pages in and out as your calculation runs will slow your system to a crawl.

It would be better, if it's possible, to upgrade your physical RAM  to 16 GB, then allow 32 GB of swap -- you'll still be swapping a lot, but you're less likely to think your machine has frozen.